# List of Dictionary words without apostrophes

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am looking for a dictionary file containing only words without apostrophes. I cant seem to find one! Does anyone know how where I can find one, if not how could I eliminate those words from the file using Python?

Comment: Give us sample for input and exp output

Comment: @ArtsiomRudzenka Sample Input: A dictionary file. Sample Output: a dictionary file minus words containing apostrophes.

Comment: Post that dictionary in the question body?

Comment: The way I understood the question is the OP needs a dictionary which contains words without apostrophes and if one doesn't exist how can he process one with apostrophes using python. I didn't think he was talking about `python dictionary/list`. Please can you clarify what you mean.

Comment: @sudo_o That is exactly what I want. I downloaded just a simple .txt list of words from the dictionary 150000 to be exact and for my purposes I need to eliminate all the ones which have apostrophes. How can I do so?

Comment: Sounds like you are going to use this `dictionary` for dictionary attack?

Comment: If you are using Linux see my answer, my words file *(fedora 17)* contains ~500,000 words with-out `'` and comes *pre-installed*

Answer (score 1):

To check on whether any char is in string or list you can use 'in' the following way:

```
words = ["it's", "my", "world"]
filtered = [x for x in words if "'" not in x]
>>> ["my", "world"]
```

Or the same but without list comprehension used in a first one:

```
filtered = []
for x in words:
    if "'" not in x:
        filtered.append(x)
```

In case you have dictionary where keys are words that you need to filter:

```
newDict = {}
for k,v in wordsDict.iteritems():
    if "'" not in k:
        newDict[k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

**On Linux:**

A nice method using `grep` to filter out any words containing apostrophes in the `words` file and save to `mywords.txt` in your home directory.

`grep "^[^']*$" /usr/share/dict/words > ~/mywords.txt`

No need to install, download or write any code!

---

**On OS X:**

Even easier as `/usr/share/dict/words` contains no words with apostrophes in already.

Comment: Im rather new to this so I'm not sure excatly what to do. I am using Mac by the way.

Comment: Get a `terminal` found in `Utilities>Terminal` on mac and copy & paste `grep "^[^']*$" /usr/share/dict/words > ~/mywords.txt` to the terminal, this will create a new file called `mywords.txt` in your home directory.

Comment: >>> grep "^[^']*$" /usr/share/dict/words > ~/mywords.txt
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    grep "^[^']*$" /usr/share/dict/words > ~/mywords.txt
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Okay so I logged into a mac and I looked at the file `/usr/share/dict/words` and none of the words contained `'` by default. The number of words is about 250,000 so it seems you had the file you wanted all along :)

Answer (score 0):

use the built-in function [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda x:"'" not in x,my_list)
```

example:

```
In [19]: my_list=['foo', "bar's", "don't","bar"]

In [20]: filter(lambda x:"'" not in x,my_list)
Out[20]: ['foo', 'bar']
```

From the Docs:

```
filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
```

> Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
>   function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a
>   tuple or string, return the same type, else return a list.

Comment: also once they are returned they have quotations around them.

Comment: @user1832195 can't you post a small snippet of your file in the question body and as well as expected output? this will make the question more clear.